# Terraform retry not waiting

Tags: terraform

We have this in our tf file

```
terraform {
  backend "http" {
    address        = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo"
    lock_address   = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo/lock"
    unlock_address = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo/lock"
    lock_method    = "POST"
    unlock_method  = "DELETE"
    retry_wait_min = 5
    retry_max      = 5
  }
```

We often get 429'ed by gitlab (rate limited). But when we get one, the retry doesn't seem to wait...  I see this in the logs

```
2023-12-21T21:55:27.866Z [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo?ID=<id> (status: 429): retrying in 0s (5 left)
26442023-12-21T21:55:27.922Z [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo?ID=<id> (status: 429): retrying in 0s (4 left)
26452023-12-21T21:55:27.967Z [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo?ID=<id> (status: 429): retrying in 0s (3 left)
26462023-12-21T21:55:28.036Z [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo?ID=<id> (status: 429): retrying in 0s (2 left)
26472023-12-21T21:55:28.069Z [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/terraform/state/foo?ID=<id> (status: 429): retrying in 0s (1 left)
```

So of course since it isn't waiting, it is going to cause more 429's because the extra filed calls probably count against us.  Essentially it is extending the amount of time we are rate limited, and of course means the job is going to fail.

Any ideas why it isn't waiting, or what to look at to try and figure that out?

Comment: May there be a variable named `TF_HTTP_RETRY_WAIT_MIN` exported in the environment set to `0`?

Comment: @LorenzoFelletti Great thought.  I am going to go with maybe.  We aren't setting it, and our output doesn't show it.  But gitlab docs say they would set it in some circumstances... but they would set it to 5.  So I will have to dig deeper to be absolutely sure it isn't set.